# How to delete a contact in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider, android-menu, android-context

I have a `listview` and I called `registerForContextMenu`. In the `ContextMenu` I only have one menu is "Delete Contact". Below is the code when it is clicked delete menu:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
        menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int id = menuinfo.position;
        delete(id);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


 private void delete(int id)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        try{
            String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.
                Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            System.out.println("The uri is " + uri.toString());
            cr.delete(uri, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + "=" + id, null);
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
        }
}
```

But with the above code there is no detail data is erased.
My question is whether any of the above code is missing or if it is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `id` from the `AdapterContextMenuInfo`:

```
long id = menuinfo.id;
```

Right now you're using the `position`, which represents the position of the selected row in the adapter and not the `id` of the contact for that particular row so when you look for the contact with that `id` you'll, most probably, not find it.

Comment: I change positions with the id and type id = int I replace long. finally it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fuji Sorry, `id` must be set as a `long` value.